# How to help Intellisense so it lists event handlers in my aspx pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, intellisense

I've got a custom button control that handles an OnServerClick. My aspx dev's are asking me if it would be possible to influence Intellisense so it will give me all the possible event handlers for that page. Is this possible?

Basically I would like to have auto completion on my OnServerClick events in my ASPX pages (just like when I would have an enum).

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to get intellisense on server side events in the aspx.

It probably only works in the designer. When your dev's want to see the possible handlers, they can check out the designer and view the click eventhandlers in button properties / events / click.

Simply a limitation / bug / you name it of Visual Studio 2010 and lower.

But: maybe VS 2011 will make you happy! :

> In VS 2011 Developer preview, markup intellisense for all ASP.NET
>   server-side events will show you list of exiting handlers and a value
>   called “Create New Event” . Which means you can attach the event
>   with some exiting event handler or  select “create New event” to
>   generate an new  handler with the right signature in the code-behind
>   file.

For more info and screenshots:
[Server Side Event Handler Generation From ASP.NET Markup in Visual Studio 2011 Developer Preview](http://dailydotnettips.com/2011/10/19/server-side-event-handler-generation-from-asp-net-markup-in-visual-studio-2011-developer-preview/)